# Three UIPickerViews in one ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, viewcontroller

I have three UIPickerViews, which i use in one ViewController. It need to be independent from each other, because i need to save result from each, but when i run it it see three pickerView which save d the same result also,when you choose different UIPickerView.  ViewController.m file:

```
 @interface ViewController (){
 NSArray *_pickerData;
 NSArray *_pickerData2;
 NSArray *_pickerData3;

__weak IBOutlet UITextField *max;
__weak IBOutlet UITextField *m2;
__weak IBOutlet UITextField *m3;
 }
@end

@implementation ViewController


   - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
 _pickerData = @[@"Apple",@"Avocado",@"Asparagus",@"Grapefruit"];
    _pickerData2 = @[@"Apple",@"Avocado",@"Asparagus",@"Grapefruit"];
    _pickerData3 = @[@"Apple",@"Avocado",@"Asparagus",@"Grapefruit"];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.picker.dataSource = self;
self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker2.dataSource = self;
self.picker2.delegate = self;
self.picker3.dataSource = self;
self.picker3.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
// The number of columns of data
- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
 {
return 1;
 }

 // The number of rows of data
 - (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
return _pickerData.count;
  }
  - (int)picker2View:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
  {
return _pickerData2.count;
  }
  - (int)picker3View:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
  {
return _pickerData3.count;
  }
 - (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:           (NSInteger)component                    
   {
   self->max.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _pickerData[row]];

    return _pickerData[row];

    }
   - (NSString*)pickerView2:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent: (NSInteger)component
     {
     self->m2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _pickerData2[row]];
     return _pickerData2[row];
      }
  - (NSString*)pickerView3:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:   (NSInteger)component
      {
       self->m3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _pickerData2[row]];
       return _pickerData3[row];
       }
       @end
```

When i run it three PickerView work like one.ViewController.h file:

```
       #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

      @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
      @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
      @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker2;
      @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker3;
      @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to implement 3 different (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component. I am assuming you have 3 textfields that should bring up a UIPickerView for when a user taps on the TextField. You do not need 3 different UIPickerViews either

You will need to have three booleans Bool firstTextFieldActive, Bool secondTextFieldActive, Bool thirdTextFieldActive, set all these to default "NO" in viewDidLoad.

Once the user taps on a particular TextField set its respective boolean to "YES"

For Example: Lets say the user tapped on "max", then this make the compiler call "(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField", here you will check which text field is being edited with the following code

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if([textField isEqual: max]){

        //First textfield is being edited
        firstTextFieldActive = YES;
        //Make sure the other textfield actives are set to NO
        secondTextFieldActive = NO;
        thirdTextFieldActive = NO;
        //Now reload pickerView
        [picker reloadAllComponents];
    }
}
```

After this in your

```
-(int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    if(firstTextFieldActive){
        return _pickerData.count;
    }else if(secondTextFieldActive){
        return _pickerData2.count;
    }else if(thirdTextFieldActive){
        return _pickerData3.count;
    }
}
```

Also only implement only one of these

```
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component                    
{
    if(firstTextFieldActive){
        self->max.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _pickerData[row]];

        return _pickerData[row];
    }else if(secondTextFieldActive){
        self->m2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _pickerData2[row]];
        return _pickerData2[row];
    }else if(thirdTextFieldActive){
        self->m3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _pickerData2[row]];
        return _pickerData3[row];
    }
}
```

**Hope This helps**

Answer (score 2):

The delegate and datasource methods which get called are the same for all of the picker views.  The difference will be in the pickerView argument which is passed to the method.  So, for example, rather than:

```
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}
- (int)picker2View:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData2.count;
}
- (int)picker3View:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData3.count;
}
```

You should have:

```
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == self.picker) {
        return _pickerData.count;
    } else if (pickerView == self.picker2) {
        return _pickerData2.count;
    } else if (pickerView == self.picker3) {
        return _pickerData3.count;
    }
}
```

And so on for all the other delegate/datasource methods.

Answer (score 0):

You've repeated the delegate methods - that's not how delegate methods work. 
The only ones of the 6 methods above that actually work will be the 1st in each group - those are the actual delegate methods your UIPickerView will call. The others will never get hit. That's why they all seem to act identically.

The `pickerView` argument passed to the delegate methods already tells you which of the 3 it is. 
You need to get the pickerView by comparing the one passed into the method to the @property you've declared in the viewController's .h. Also, they probably don't need to be in the .h.

```
 //The following is the only one of the 3 "titleForRow" methods that's working
 - (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:           (NSInteger)component                    
   {
   //...result is that they're all set to the same array value Don't use the following line.
   //self->max.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _pickerData[row]];

  //use this instead to determine which UIPicker the argument `pickerView` refers to
  if (pickerView == self.picker) {
    return _pickerData[row]; //this assumes the data array has an NSString value for this row. What if it doesn't?  
   } else if ... //looks like pbasdf already mentioned this approach above... Account for the 3 options

   return nil; //after all the if/else branches, in case pickerView or row are nil, since you have to return something  
}


- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
     //check the "pickerView" argument against your @properties. @pbasdf beat me to it! 
    //Same if/else check as the other delegate methods
    //then return the correct _pickerData.count; //
  }
```